# How to skip duplicatives and/or group entries in php query?

Tags: php

In my database, I have a "contract" column. The column has many duplicate contract numbers. The code I have below echos all the rows within the database. I'm trying to ignore/skip/group the duplicatives but the code that I have below didn't do much justice. I did some research online and couldn't make sense on how to get this right. Any suggestions?

```
$list = $DB_CON_C->query("SELECT * FROM account ORDER BY `id` DESC");
$order = array();
$data_row .= '<option value="New Order">New Order</option>'."\n";

if($list !== false) {
  foreach($list as $row) {
    $order[] = array_unique($row['contract']);
    $data_row .=  '<option value="'.$order[].'">'.$order[].'</option>'."\n";
  }
}
echo $data_row;
unset($row);
```

Comment: What your query returns? Where is array dump?
Better show a data structure, but not describing it.
Anyway, I suggest you to modify your query and use DISTINCT or GROUP BY.

Comment: Why not just select from the contract table instead? Unless... there is no contract table :(

Comment: It gave me this error: Fatal error: Cannot use [] for reading.

Comment: I don't have a contract table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in your SQL statement with out any php manipulation.

```
SELECT *
FROM `account` 
GROUP BY `contract`
```

You can refer your self to https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
It contains a few examples of how it can be used.

```
$list = $DB_CON_C->query("SELECT contract FROM `account` GROUP BY `contract`");
$data_row .= '<option value="New Order">New Order</option>'."\n";

if($list !== false) {
  foreach($list as $row) {
    $data_row .=  '<option value="'.$row['contract'].'">'.$row['contract'].'</option>'."\n";
  }
}
echo $data_row;
unset($row);
```

Comment: Actually I tried this first initially and it gave me an error: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the order by id or add id in the selected columns?

Comment: Thanks, it works when I take out the order by ID. So how do I do order by ID desc order?

Comment: Ignore my previous question. Order by ID is irrelevant. Thanks for the help. Could you edit you response by taking out order by id so I can accept your answer?

Comment: Perfect! Glad it helped. I made the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Per the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) for `array_unique()`, it's not intended for multidimensional arrays. If you look at that page, the first answer has a good method for deduping a multidimensional array based on a specific key.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you could store the orders in an array() and perform a check if the value already exists.

```
foreach($list as $row) {
    if(!in_array($row['contract'], $order)){
        $order[] = $row['contract'];
    }
}
```

And then run a new foreach loop to populate your `<option>` element

```
foreach($order as $ord){
    $data_row .=  '<option value="'.$ord.'">'.$ord.'</option>'."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I have tried so many ways, it seems like a simple thing to do but this crap is driving me nut.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the behavior? Though, as @PatrickSimard pointed out it's probably better to handle it in the query.

Comment: Sweet! And good luck with your project. Actually just noticed the mistake in my own example, but not gonna go into that now that you got it working the correct way^